# How to stream video to remote server and then to others

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming

Im completely new on video streaming, but i need to develop a software that allows me to stream 1 or multiple ip cameras from a local machine, to a remote one (both linux), and allow other people to watch it through a java app.

Have any idea from where to start?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: here are approaches on using HTML5 to capture webcam video directly from the browser which you could then stream to the server http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/   ... also google this :    html5 video capture stream to server

Comment: In addition, I would think it might be easiest to split this into two when planning it - first step is to stream from local machine to 'server'; second step is for server to provide streams to any clients that want to watch.